# How to find coordinate of polygon shape from binary image?

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, scipy.ndimage

The image is below, where `dark area` is `0`, `bright area` is `255`. I want to find `4` coordinates `[(x1, y1),(x2, y2),(x3, y3),(x4, y4)]`  of `bright area` from this image. This `bright area` would be `polygon shape` `(pentagon, hexagon, triangle etc.)`.

I have tried with `cv2.findContours()` function like following code:

```
# Find contour(s)
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(bin_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)    
print(cnts)
```

I also have tried with `np.where()` function like following code:

```
idx_points = np.where(bin_img == 255)
print(idx_points)
```

I can't find out expected result like `[(x1, y1),(x2, y2),(x3, y3),(x4, y4),(x5,y5), ...]`. What can I do this for expected result?

[image]

Comment: play with approxPolyDP, see [here](https://dev.to/simarpreetsingh019/detecting-geometrical-shapes-in-an-image-using-opencv-4g72) and [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on their tutorial, https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html, this is exactly what `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` would do for you:

[image]

The left part image shows `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE`, keeping all contour points, without trying anything. The right part shows `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` attempting to recognize and store corners only. (Image comes from the same tutorial page)